# Rename unity [component] tags to [unity-component] to prevent confusion with gnome components

Tags: discussion, tags

Well, now GNOME and Unity has some shared names with certain parts of the UI, [namely the "launcher" and the "dash"](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Design). There is already a tag for the unity dash and the unity launcher that are being confused (with motive) with their GNOME equivalent since people don't read the excerpts. So I ask that the tags for components of Unity to be renamed to [unity-component](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity-component) without synonym, so users become aware of these tags.

I will not be surprised that there are other components that share the same name in Unity and GNOME (or any other desktop environment for what counts) so this is a sensible action thinking on the future since it disambiguates the usage and lift load on the [unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity).

Bonus points: users that follow the unity tag, can follow instead `unity*` which will feed them with all the unity related tagged questions.